# Primefaces Dialog Framework - Not Working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, dialog-framework

Primefaces Dialog Framework v 4 is not working, I have googled to solve the problem as I have added the following code to faces config but all went in vain. Please find the code below:

Index page:

```
<p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{dialogBean.viewCars}" />
```

Bean Code:

```
 public void viewCars() {  
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("viewCars");  
}
```

faces config:

```
<application>   <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
<navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
<view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler></application>
```

TypeError: this.jq.draggable is not a function
in  /faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&v=4.0
[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Try this:RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("viewCars.show()"), is it working?

Comment: ReferenceError: viewCars is not defined viewCars.show();

Comment: jquery-plugins.js is somehow missing on page, try to add it manually. h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"

Comment: Thanks  Cagatay Civici .... its working

Answer (score 1):

As Cagatay Civici said you must add to the header of your page this line:

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
```

Don't worry - do not copy any files to your project - above line is enough because PrimeFaces automatically adds js file.

But you must also add few lines to your faces-config.xml file:

```
<application>
  <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
  <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
  <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

You may also read [this](http://lauraliparulo.altervista.org/primefaces-dialog-framework-how-to-make-it-work/) article of Laura Liparulo.