# Primefaces dialog framework doesn't show up

Tags: primefaces, dialog, dialog-framework

Yet another post on **primefaces** dialog framework.

I've been watching all of these previous posts:

[Primefaces Dialog Framework - Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328768/primefaces-dialog-framework-not-working)

[primefaces dialog using dialog framework not popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532034/primefaces-dialog-using-dialog-framework-not-popping-up)

[Primefaces dialog framework not working while using ajax listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679006/primefaces-dialog-framework-not-working-while-using-ajax-listener)

I've been trying all of these but still the dialog just doesn't show up.\

I'm using `primefaces 5.1`.

Let me add some details.

Page with a button that should call the dialog:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

  <h:form>
      <p:commandButton 
         value="prova popup" 
         actionListener="#{codTribEr.chooseCodiceErario('/popup/codice-erario.xhtml')}">
      </p:commandButton>
  </h:form>

</html>
```

Java code:

```java
package it.iwb.ubiss.poc.popup;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean(name="codTribEr")
@ViewScoped
public class CodiceTributoErario implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void chooseCodiceErario(String s) {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect structure of JSF.

1. You did not use JSF Standard tags(h:head, h:body).
2. You pass cannot pass parameter through argument of actionListener because the actionListener only accept ActionEvent parameter. If you want to pass parameter through actionListener, you can achieve by `f:attribute`

The example code is shown below.

xhtml

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>prova popup</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="prova popup" 
                             actionListener="#{codTribEr.chooseCodiceErario}"
                             >
                <f:attribute name="url" value="/popup/codice-erario.xhtml" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

managedbean

```java
package it.iwb.ubiss.poc.popup;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean(name = "codTribEr")
@ViewScoped
public class CodiceTributoErario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void chooseCodiceErario(ActionEvent event) {
        String url = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("url");
        System.out.println(url);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(url);
    }
}
```

codice-erario.xhtml

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>codice-erario</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        Show codice-erario.xhtml
    </h:body>

</html>
```